# Are there only discrete and continuous time dynamic systems

Tags: general-topology, stochastic-processes, dynamical-systems

Learning about dynamic systems, deterministic or stochastic, one deals either with a trajectory given by $(X_\alpha)_{\alpha \in A}$ where for a discrete-time process $A = \Bbb N$ and for a continuous time process $A = \Bbb R_+$. From what little I know about Markov random fields, the index set $A$ can also $\Bbb R^n$, but for now I would like to just focus attention on direct analogs of time-based processes.

Are there any good mathematical reasons why we do not work with anything but $A = \Bbb N, \Bbb R_+$? For one thing, from our concept of time it seems to follow that $A$ must be a totally ordered set $(1)$. Perhaps, since a lot of things are done over a finite time horizon, we need such subsets of the index set to be compact, so $A$ must be $\sigma$-compact. Yet, seems the time may need to flow unbounded, $A$ itself must be non-compact. I guess for technical reasons to work with limits over such trajectories it is important that $A$ complete. And also likely $A$ must be homogeneous to talk about time translations.

Question is: are there any math models that use time index set $A$ not being $\Bbb N$ or $\Bbb R_+$ and if not, are there any good reasons for that. In particular, is that the case that a totally ordered set $A$ which is non-compact, $\sigma$-compact, complete and homogeneous in its order topology is isomorphic to an open subset of $\Bbb Z$ or $\Bbb R$?

Comment: Do you want an answer to: "are there any math models that use time index set $A$ not being $\Bbb N$ or $\Bbb R_+$ and if not, are there any good reasons for that"? OR "In particular, is that the case that a totally ordered set $A$ which is non-compact, $\sigma$-compact, complete and homogeneous in its order topology is isomorphic to an open subset of $\Bbb Z$ or $\Bbb R$?" Note that the two questions are completely unrelated.

Comment: I’m more interest in the former. The latter I can ask as a separate question on topology if you suggest @JohnB

Comment: I'm sorry for the delay. I answered to your first question. I would suggest that you ask the second question separately.

Answer (score 3):

Let me reply to the first question: there are **many** such models.

For details and many developments I recommend the books:

- by [Feres](https://www.cambridge.org/us/universitypress/subjects/mathematics/differential-and-integral-equations-dynamical-systems-and-co/dynamical-systems-and-semisimple-groups-introduction?format=PB&isbn=9780521142168) for an emphasis on the relation to ergodic theory and actions of noncompact Lie groups;
- by [Zimmer](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-1-4684-9488-4) for an emphasis on the study of lattices and rigidity (also on Margulis' work);
- by [Katok and Nitica](https://www.cambridge.org/us/universitypress/subjects/mathematics/differential-and-integral-equations-dynamical-systems-and-co/rigidity-higher-rank-abelian-group-actions-volume-1?format=HB) on higher rank Abelian actions and hyperbolicity.

Note that higher rank Abelian action may be given by $\mathbb R^k$ or $\mathbb Z^k$. This diversity of developments and applications answers to your first question and indeed there are **many** such models.

But to give specific important examples, I would suggest looking at papers:

- by [Afraimovich and Chow](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF03167235) on topological spatial chaos and homoclinic points of higher rank actions (it may come for example from discretizing a partial differential equation or from an infinite lattice of coupled oscillators);
- by [Afraimovich and Pesin](https://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1088/0951-7715/6/3/006/pdf) on the hyperbolicity of travelling waves in lattice models (it is natural to consider a $\mathbb Z^2$ action with the two independent directions relating to space and some discrete time).

I regret that it would be too much to detail here since all this requires a lot of preparations.

Comment: Thanks for the answers.  don’t these models as you say have time as just one variable in the index set while other dimensions represent something else, eg space?

Comment: @SBF Not in general, but of course yes in the work of Afraimovich and Pesin.